# How to disable multi-threading in mgcv::gam() function?

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I'm trying to find a way in which R mgcv::gam() uses only one core on Windows or Linux machine with Intel CPU.

Although I specified `control=list(nthreads=1)` within gam() function, R seems to be using about 60% of CPU of my 24-core 48-thread machine when checked with task manager.

The reason I want to force single-thread calculation is that I want to perform >10^5 gam() calculation. Multi-threading within gam() does not speed up in proportion to the number of threads, so in theory it will be faster to perform single-threaded gam()'s in parallelized threads of parallel::parLapply().

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I would use `control = gam.control(nthreads = 1)` but, as that's the default, that can't be the issue. I suspect you are running a multithreaded BLAS and `gam()` through R is using that for some aspects of the fit that involve linear algebra. You'll need to  check what BLAS you are using and swap it out for a single threaded one perhaps. At least it's something to check.

Comment: Yeah, just going to second what Gavin said. I've found that with a bunch of packages, they will use all available cores for the matrix multiplication regardless of the number of cores you specify.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I'm using Microsoft R Open, which is built upon Intel MKL. I specified `setMKLthreads(1)` together with `control = gam.control(nthreads = 1)` but still get the same CPU usage.